# Cannot use "and" operand to filter ETDataExtensionRow

Tags: fuel-sdk, java

Now, I'm working on Java Fuel-SDK and I need to use "and" on select method.
I look on example code of Fuel-SDK, I found ET deprecated ETFilter and put "SQL like" syntax on method, Example.

```
@Test
public void _50_TestSelectFilteredAndStatic()
    throws ETSdkException
{
    ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> response = ETDataExtension.select(client,
                                                                     "key=test1",
                                                                     "LastName=Flintstone and FirstName = 'Wilma'");
    testSelectFilteredAnd(response);
}
```

But, when I tried on my code. It dose not work, no data return.
*below is my code.

```
val response = dbUnsubscribe.select(s"$eventFrom <= EventDate and EventDate <= $eventTo", "order by EventDate")
```

*Scala code.

Comment: even it is Scala, you would use `&&` not `and`

Comment: && is not work, but I found already.  Thx guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add ['..'] in SQL and it's work.

```
val response = dbUnsubscribe.select(s"EventDate >= '$eventFrom' and EventDate <= '$eventTo'", "order by EventDate")
```

Comment: In the interest of helping others can you put a brief explanation why that solved it and mark your answer correct?

Comment: I have no idea how to explain.  Example of ET is 
"LastName=Flintstone and FirstName = 'Wilma'"  but I use something like this
"LastName='Flintstone' and FirstName = 'Wilma'"